# Type error: Module '"@emotion/react"' has no exported member 'css'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, emotion

Probably an amateur question but I cannot fix it.

I did `yarn add @emotion/styled && yarn add @emotion/react` to use in Next.JS
I runs perfectly fine in dev mode `yarn run dev` but I cannot build it due to the error saying

```
Type error: Module '"@emotion/react"' has no exported member 'css'.

> 1 | import { css } from "@emotion/react";
    |          ^
  2 |
  3 | export const containerStyle = css
```

This happens in Global, ThemeProvider also.

These are the versions that I am using (latest).

```
    "@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.8.1",
    ...
    "next": "12.1.0",
```

Any suggestions will help this beginner a lot.

Comment: Could you post entirety of your `package.json` that show the `dependencies`section.

Comment: Sorry I just saw this. I fixed it by typing `import @emotion/react` in emotion.d.ts